# Result Set vacio con Prepared Statement en java contra Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Buenas!

Tengo el siguiente código que no está devolviendo ningún dato al `ResultSet` definido:

```
Connection _con = null;
PreparedStatement _ps = null;
ResultSet _rs = null;
UsuarioBean _Ret = null;

_con = (new ConEvaluacionProveedores()).getConexion();
_ps = _con.prepareStatement("SELECT * from EPUsuario WHERE UsuCod = ? AND UsuPsw = ?");
_ps.setInt(1, pUsuario.getCedula());
_ps.setString(2, pUsuario.getContrasenia());

_rs = _ps.executeQuery();
while (_rs.next()){
    _Ret = BuscarUsuario(pUsuario);
}
```

La BD contra la que lo ejecuto es *Oracle*, y si ejecuto exactamente lo mismo contra *Postgres* me devuelve correctamente los datos.

Si la consulta la hago utilizando `java.sql.Statement` me devuelve datos correctamente.

Existe alguna restricción en el uso de `java.sql.PreparedStatement` contra *Oracle* o algo que pueda no estar tomando en cuenta?.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Explica por favor qué resultado estás obteniendo ¿Un ResultSet vacío? ¿Una excepción que no estás controlando?

Como comentario decirte que deberías cerrar los recursos en un bloque finally o utilizando un try-con-recursos de Java7.

Comment: Con "no esta devolviendo ningun dato" me refería a que el ResultSet queda vacío. No da ninguna excepción.
Es un extracto del código, en la versión completa cierro tanto la conexión como el PreparedStatement y controlo las excepciones. Me pareció innecesario postear también eso.
Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: ¿Has probado seteando manualmente dos valores cualesquiera existentes exactamente como están registrados en la BD en los dos parámetros del preparedStatement para ver si tampoco así devuelve resultados?

Comment: Otra cosa a tomar en cuenta es si alguno de tus campos del WHERE son del tipo CHAR. Si es así te recomiendo que leas esto: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-oracle-char-field-preparedstatement.html

Comment: No lo había probado. Acabo de probarlo y asi si funciona.
Pero igual si debugueo, los datos que se pasan por parametros son exactamente iguales a los valores que pongo harcoded para que funcione.

Comment: @A. Cedano muchas gracias. Agregue un "TRIM()" a la consulta como recomienda el link que comentaste y empezó a funcionar. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Sería bueno que quede como respuesta y sea marcada como solución para que pueda servir a otros y la pregunta no quede abierta.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Ponelo como respuesta y la marco como correcta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es conocido que en Oracle, las consultas con `WHERE` que incluyen campos del tipo `CHAR` suelen dar problemas en el sentido de que, si tienes por ejemplo la columna `UsuPsw` del tipo `CHAR (9)` y en ella tienes esto: 
`123456   .`

```
                        ^^^
                        habrá espacios en blanco 
                        hasta llegar a un total de nueve caracteres.
```

al querer compararlo con la cadena `123456` no coincidirá, porque al tener un campo `CHAR` de tamaño fijo, Oracle lo rellenará a la derecha con caracteres en blanco.

Varias soluciones existen:

- Usar `TRIM` para evitar los espacios en blanco vacíos.
- Definir el campo del tipo `VARCHAR` en vez de `CHAR`
- Indicar a la consulta que añada los posibles caracteres en blanco de relleno con `RPAD`

Hay otras soluciones y consideraciones a tomar en cuenta, dependerá del contexto de tu aplicación, de los datos que manejas y cómo los manejas, aplicar la que sea más eficaz.

[Aquí](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-oracle-char-field-preparedstatement.html) podrás encontrar otros detalles que podrían ayudar.

Comment: Esto es efectivamente muy cierto. No pusiste la estructura de la BD, pero si utilizaste CHAR en lugar de VARCHAR (ó NVARCHAR) te puedes encontrar con este problema.

Answer (score 0):

No hay ninguna diferencia en *Oracle* que provoque un error como el que comentas, sin embargo sí que hay algunas diferencias entre la **configuración por defecto** de un motor y de otro, y puede que por ahí venga tu problema.

Por ejemplo *Oracle* suele estar configurado por defecto para distinguir las mayúsculas de las minúsculas, al contrario que otros motores, con lo que tu consulta podría funcionar simplemente cambiándola por esta otra:

```
SELECT * from EPUsuario WHERE UPPER(UsuCod) = ? AND UPPER(UsuPsw) = ?
```

Y por supuesto haciendo `.toUpperCase()` de las cadenas de entrada.

Otro problema que veo en tu código es que **no cierras ningún recurso**. Imagino que no has controlado las excepciones porque este código es un ejemplo para esta web, pero deberías siempre cerrar los recursos en un bloque *finally* o, si tienes *Java7* o superior, utilizando un try-con-recursos.

Comment: Primero, gracias por tu respuesta.

En mi caso me interesa que la consulta sea "Case Sensitive" porque la contraseña puede tener mayusculas y minusculas. Y el Primer parámetro al ser un int no tendría ese problema.

Y con respecto a los recursos, como te comentaba en el comentario, si los estoy cerrando y controlando las excepciones, solo que omití incluirlo porque me parecio innecesario para reflejar el problema que estaba teniendo.

Comment: Como te digo en mi respuesta no debería haber diferencia. Te sugiero ejecutar las mismas consultas a mano desde Oracle para comprobar que realmente devuelve lo que esperas.